# i want my public ip address to show on a textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

i tried using a variable which its name is "a" to be equal to the web ip address then what the variable gets, will be equal to the textbox, but it is get the public ip address but the variable "a" is notreading the ip address, below is the code.

please i really need help

```
        private void ipvvvv(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string a;

            var endpoint = "https://api.ipify.org/";
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endpoint);
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            var resstream = response.GetResponseStream();
            var streamreader = new StreamReader(resstream);
            MessageBox.Show($"Public Ip Address: {streamreader.ReadToEnd()}");
            a =  streamreader.ReadToEnd();

            a = eyoip.Text;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean you read the `streamread` twice, and it return 2 different results ?
Maybe It's a problem with the byte order mark. Improve by setting

```
streamrerader.BaseStream.Position
```

Or try to remove this line:

```
MessageBox.Show($"Public Ip Address: {streamreader.ReadToEnd()}");
```

Comment: you dont understand what i want

Comment: @SMARTG. truth to be told I have trouble understanding your question too. Could you please clarify it by editing the question?

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
 a = eyoip.Text;
```

Should instead be

```
eyoip.Text = a;
```

And also you should reuse the variable instead of reading the stream twice:

```
a = streamreader.ReadToEnd();
MessageBox.Show($"Public Ip Address: {a}");
eyoip.Text = a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var endpoint = "https://api.ipify.org/";
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var externalIP = client.GetStringAsync(endpoint).Result;
    //Console.WriteLine($"external IP {externalIP}");

    eyoip.Text = externalIP;
}
```

HttpClient can be used to avoid streams processing since external IP is a short string value.

to assign the IP to the textbox you have to change the `a = eyoip.Text;` to `eyoip.Text = a;` as @meJustAndrew said (if eyoip is a textbox name). This will assign `a` variable value to the `eyoip` text box `Text` property.

PS: However there is WPF tag so you can read about model-view-controller pattern and move external IP code from `ipvvvv` button click handler to the new class.